# Checking If Any WPF DataGrid Cell Has Error

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I have validation set up on the cells and it works as expected (placing a red highlight around the textbox and adding a tooltip with the error). However, If I try to access Validation.GetHasError(TheGrid) where TheGrid is my DataGrid, it is always false. Does anyone know how to check if ANY cells in the DataGrid have errors?

I want to do this so I can disable saving if there are errors.

Comment: I think my answer to [this question][1] solves it in a more XAML friendly way.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121892/wpf-detect-row-validation-errors-in-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might run into problems with virtualization with this but you probably do have to look at the containers:

```
var errors = (from c in
                  (from object i in _myGrid.ItemsSource
                   select _myGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(i))
              where c != null
              select Validation.GetHasError(c))
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x);
if (errors)
{
    //There be errors
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I ended up doing but instead of looking through the controls I checked the Errors property on my data that the xaml was bound to.

Comment: @KrisTrip: If you can bind it to data that of course is always to be preferred, normally one should not need to ever mess with the generated containers.