# WPF: Detect row validation errors in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I want to achieve a pretty simple task, but none of the solutions here on SO or otherwise found have helped me so far:

I have a WPF `DataGrid`, which is bound to a typed data set. When I click the OK button in my window, I want to detect whether there are currently any row validation errors. I want to show a message box and tell the user to resolve these errors.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**
To make my question a bit more precise:

The typed dataset I'm binding to is a simple data set that contains a table. The tables is filled from a call to a WCF service and there are 5 text columns in the table. Some of these columns have length constraints (for example, one column may only take 5 characters).

The `ItemsSource` of my `GridView` is set in code as follows:

```
dgvData.ItemsSource = m_dataModel.TableName;
```

If I enter some text into the columns, all is well. Entering more than 5 characters into said column, the red row error marker is displayed next to the row. I am not doing any custom validation (yet).

I can see the red exclamation mark, but I'm not able to determine in code whether it is visible or not. I've tried to:

- Use the data set's `HasErrors` property (returns `false`)
- `Validation.GetHasErrors(dgvData)` returns `false` as well
- the soluction H.B.'s mentioned in his comment, but it didn't work

I'm at a loss here - there must be a simple way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking If Any WPF DataGrid Cell Has Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017611/checking-if-any-wpf-datagrid-cell-has-error)

Comment: @H.B.: I've tried the solution provided there: Does not work.

Comment: That's some bloody precise feedback...

Comment: Well, what more do you want me to say? I have copied to code snipped from the accepted solution into my handler for the OK button. Then I've replaced the name `_myGrid` with the name of my grid control - `errors` is false no matter what I try even though my grid is showing a row error.

Comment: Just copying things is not a good idea. How about stepping through it to see what it is doing? I suspect that your ItemsSource is the problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I've worked it out. The following does what I want:

```
public static DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid grid, int index)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    if (row == null)
    {
        // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
        grid.UpdateLayout();
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }
    return row;
}
```

In the code for my "OK" button I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvData.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = GetRow(dgvData, i);
    if (row != null && Validation.GetHasError(row))
    {
        hasDataGridErrors = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you catch the attached bubbling routed event `Validation.Error` on your data grid?

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="mydataGrid" Validation.Error="MyValidationErrorHandler" ... />
```

Make sure you have `NotifyOnValidationError=true` in your bindings. This way you would know that error has been raised and show that in your messagebox.

But do you really "know" there are errors on the datagrid? I mean do you see the errors highlighted using red border , tooltips, row validation error template etc? Isnt that sufficient to indicate to user?

Cant you use

```
  Validation.GetHasError(mydataGrid)
```

to check if its in error?

Comment: I will try catching the event. The thing is: I'm reading data from a WCF-service into a typed dataset. Then I want the user to modify the data and on "OK" send the data back to the WCF-service. I just want to make sure that I do not send unless all errors are resolved.

Comment: Neither of these seem to work when using row-level validation.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a near duplicate of this [question]: ([Checking If Any WPF DataGrid Cell Has Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017611/checking-if-any-wpf-datagrid-cell-has-error)).

Here's an answer that's more XAMly. It relies on the fact that when an error template is shown its IsVisible property toggles.

Just create a ValidationErrorTemplate for the DataGridRow [1]: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975.aspx)

Create 2 attacheded properties.  The value of the one attached property is the DataGrid itself,

```
local:DataGridValidator.DataGridToMarkForValidationErrors="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```

Attach the property to the root control of the ValidationErrorTemplate.

In the callback for the attached property set the 2nd property on the DataGrid to show whether it has errors:

```
        private static void DataGridPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var fe = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
        var target = args.NewValue as DependencyObject;

        if (fe != null && target != null)
        {
            target.SetValue(IsFreeOfValidatoionErrorsProperty, !fe.IsVisible);

            fe.IsVisibleChanged += (_1, _) =>
            {
                target.SetValue(IsFreeOfValidatoionErrorsProperty, !fe.IsVisible);
            };

        }
```

Now the DataGrid has a property (IsFreeOfValidatoionErrorsProperty) showing whether it has errors or not.  I made the property default positive so I could easily AND it with my VM IsDirty/CanSave property.