# WPF Validation.HasError reverse inherited?

Tags: wpf, validation

linking to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121892/wpf-detect-row-validation-errors-in-c-code/7123339#7123339)...

Just a curious question (due to lack of .Net developement environment on my machine), is `Validation.HasError` reverse inherited as in if a child element is in error will `Validation.HasError` be true for its parent and thus for the entire window as well?

If not why? Anyways `Validation.Error` is a bubbling routed event. So wouldn't it have been easier for WPF to set the value `HasError` as true for the hierachy upwards?

Answer (score 0):

Validation.Error is [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), it is set only for certain FrameworkElement instance

Thanks to this we can create error style for failed FrameworkElement, not always developers need to mark window failed when inner FrameworkElement is failed

Comment: Actually, [Validation.Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errors.aspx) is an attached property; [Validation.Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error.aspx) is an attached event

Comment: yea, it is routedevent, and what?attached event can be routed, attached property can't