# How to check if any row is invalid?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, datagrid

I noticed that entering a non-digit in my grid's column bound to a property of integer type causes the cell to be bordered my a red frame and the row to have an exclamation mark to the far left. Please note that I haven't implemented it explicitly - this is the default behavior.

After looking around in the different properties of the grid, of the source items, cells and what not, I wasn't able to find anything that would give me a straight boolean telling me that any cell is incorrectly filled out, though.

**How can I check if any row/cell (and possibly which one) is invalidly filled?**

I've checked out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee622975%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) without becoming any wiser. I've played around with the code below but the breakpoint in the method was never even hit.

Code behind

```
public class DonkeyValidator : ValidationRule
{
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
  {
    if (value is Donkey)
      return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    return new ValidationResult(false, "Not a donkey!");
  }
}
```

Markup

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...>
  <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <dispatcher:DonkeyValidator ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
  </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
  <DataGrid.Columns> ... </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please note that I'm not looking for an advanced feed-back strategy to the user. I have a *Save* button and I wish to check whether I should proceed or stop in its *OnClick* method.

Comment: What is `DonkeyValidator` ? your class name is `ThingValidator`.

Comment: Typo. I try out different approaches and pasted in incorrectly. The question is still the same (plus I've corrected the example). Good eyes, mate.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. The `ValidationRule` fires every time the Binding-Source changes (e.g. when a `DataGridCell` changes and then lost it's focus). So maybe the problem is in the data-bindings in your `DataGrid`.

Comment: @Bahman_Aries That may be so. I'll check to make sure. However, the actual question is how to check the state of being valid as a whole. Before hitting *Save and Close*, so to speak.

Comment: The binding engine checks each `ValidationRule` associated with a binding each time an input value (the binding-target) is transferred to the binding-source. This happens (mostly) when a `UIElement` with `ValidationRule` (e.g. a `DataGridRow`) lost it's focus (for example by clicking on another `DataGridRow` or clicking the save button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it once with a normal Grid, but AFAIK it works on DataGrids to. Refer to [this blog](https://erazerbrecht.wordpress.com/2015/08/21/entit-framework-data-validation/#checkErrors).

If this doesn't work you can search manually as show in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017611/checking-if-any-wpf-datagrid-cell-has-error).

Comment: It seems that the *DataGrid* is missing a useful feature. I'll accept your reply as answer but frankly speaking I was expecting more robust functionality from such a control.